# Why does Git insist that a file has been modified even after a `git checkout --`?

Tags: git, line-endings

I made a change to a couple of files locally, *without committing them*. `git status` shows:

```
>> git status
# On branch feature-ravendb
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature-ravendb' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   source/Octopus.Tentacle/Integration/PowerShell/IPowerShell.cs
#       modified:   source/Octopus.Tentacle/Integration/PowerShell/PowerShellRunner.cs
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I want to discard the changes to those files. I tried following the instructions:

```
>> git checkout -- .\source\Octopus.Tentacle\Integration\PowerShell\IPowerShell.cs
```

The command has no output. Now I run `git status` again:

```
>> git status
# On branch feature-ravendb
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/feature-ravendb' by 1 commit.
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   source/Octopus.Tentacle/Integration/PowerShell/IPowerShell.cs
#       modified:   source/Octopus.Tentacle/Integration/PowerShell/PowerShellRunner.c
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Hmm, it's pretty convinced that the file has changed. And `git diff <file>` seems to think that the whole file has changed, even though it hasn't:

```
diff --git a/source/Octopus.Tentacle/Integration/PowerShell/IPowerShell.cs b/source/Octo
--- a/source/Octopus.Tentacle/Integration/PowerShell/IPowerShell.cs
+++ b/source/Octopus.Tentacle/Integration/PowerShell/IPowerShell.cs
@@ -1,9 +1,9 @@
-<EF><BB><BF>using System;
-
-namespace Octopus.Tentacle.Integration.PowerShell
-{
-    public interface IPowerShell
-    {
-        PowerShellExecutionResult Execute(PowerShellArguments arguments);
-    }
+<EF><BB><BF>using System;
+
+namespace Octopus.Tentacle.Integration.PowerShell
+{
+    public interface IPowerShell
+    {
+        PowerShellExecutionResult Execute(PowerShellArguments arguments);
+    }
 }
\ No newline at end of file
```

How do I convince git that I really, really haven't changed the file and don't want to commit it?

**Edit**: The following commands also have **no effect** on these modifications:

- `git checkout -- .`
- `git checkout -f`
- `git reset --soft`
- `git reset --hard`

**Edit 2**: Reverting back to an older revision, stashing my changes, then clearing the stash eventually worked. It seems like my line endings are conflicting but I don't know why:

- I have `core.autocrlf` set to true
- I have a `.gitattributes` file with the line `*.cs text`

Shouldn't this be enough?

Comment: Tried to use forward slashes in path?

Comment: Just tried now, but it didn't make a difference

Comment: It might be a line-ending issue: http://help.github.com/line-endings/

Comment: `git config core.autocrlf` is true and I have a .gitattributes that makes .cs files text. Also it only affects these two files (where I made a change and reverted), not the whole repo.

Comment: I may suggest `git checkout -f` and if it won't work then `git reset --soft`, but I'm not completely sure that the latter is safe.

Comment: I just tried `git checkout -f`, `git reset --soft` and even `git reset --hard` and the files are still modified. Is there a `git reset --please-git-even-vss-can-do-this` option? :)

Comment: Try deleting the files, then do a `git reset --hard`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a core.autocrlf is false, but recently changed to true and also apply gitattributes changes for .net. After that, in many repositories, when you try to pull, I began to receive reports on the changes which not exist, and are also unable to roll back. In the end, I went back to core.autocrlf is false

Comment: Did you keep the .gitattributes?

Comment: No, also remove. I think it might work if you make a clean repository clone again after autocrlf and gitattributes changes. But I have not tried it.